# unable to get correct data using `useLazyLoadQuery` when compose fragment into query

Tags: relayjs, relay

I do see a sucessfull API request

[image]

```
const data = useLazyLoadQuery<brandQuery>(
    graphql`query
      brandQuery {
        ...brand_autoBrands
      }
    `,
    {
      first: 10,
    },
    {
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    }
  );

  console.log(data);
```

But I got following output. it is supposed to be a json object returned from my API.

[image]

brand_autoBrands fragment  somewhere

```
const autoBrands = graphql`
    fragment brand_autoBrands on AdminQuery
      @argumentDefinitions(
        first: { type: "Int", defaultValue: 10 }
        after: { type: "String", defaultValue: "" }
        last: { type: "Int" }
        before: { type: "String" }
        filters: { type: "[Filter]" }
        sorters: { type: "[Sorter]"}
      )
      @refetchable(queryName: "BrandListPaginationQuery") {
      autoBrands(first: $first, after: $after, last: $last, before: $before, filters: $filters, sorters: $sorters)
      @connection(key: "BrandList_autoBrands") {
        edges {
          node {
            ...brandFragment
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          startCursor
        }
        totalCount
      }
    }
  `;

  const {
    data,
    loadNext,
    hasNext
  } = usePaginationFragment<BrandListPaginationQuery, _>(
    autoBrands,
    props.autoBrands,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't log a fragment data object in the parent. That data belongs to the component that defined a fragment. For performance, relay needs to know that this data is fetched for a child component but the parent doesn't need to know what the actual data object is. You just need to pass the data to its component then you should be able to log it in the child component.

```
const data = useLazyLoadQuery<brandQuery>(
graphql`query
  brandQuery {
    ...brand_autoBrands
  }
`,
{
  first: 10,
},
{
  fetchPolicy: "network-only",
}
);

data && <Brand autoBrands={data} />
```